# How to make yum also install debug symbols?

Tags: debug-symbols, yum

```
yum install libevent-devel
```

How to make it also install debug symbols??

Comment: Very old question, but worth updating to clarify this is an EL-like distro up to EL7. After that, EL uses "dnf" and not "yum".

Answer (score 6):

There's a helper script debuginfo-install that will find the appropriate packages, but you still need to feed it the (base) package name(s).

Note: `dnf` (which replaced `yum`) has the same helper script (in `dnf-plugins-core`); and `gdb` on recent Fedoras (at least) will enumerate the entire listing when it's loaded for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you refer to the knotify giving you a message that you do not have debug symbols, then all you need to do is install the appropriate app-debuginfo package.

I typically use yumex, but you can do it oldschool as follows:

```
yum search app
yum install app-debuginfo
```

You might also have to manually search the stack trace for any lines that have (??)

```
#6  0xb7975bdc in ?? () from /usr/lib/libkmailprivate.so.4
```

and then manually find and install the debuginfo packages

```
yum provides "/usr/lib/libkmailprivate.so.4"
yum install found-debuginfo
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: What if `No package nginx-debuginfo available.`?

Comment: On CentOS7, when using "yum install" directly, you may need to enable a repo that provides debuginfo files. See /etc/yum.repos.d/. For "base", something like `yum --enablerepo=base-debuginfo install systemd-debuginfo`.